# Script does nothing when trying to read file

Tags: python-3.x

I have a text file with a bunch of names separated by commas.

I'm trying to read the file and then put each name into an array.

The file looks like this:

```
Billing,
Accounting,
Pediatrics,
Human Resources,
Divisional And Surgery,
```

etc...

```
import csv

with open('MentorAffiliations.txt', newline='') as csvfile:
    data = list(csv.reader(csvfile))

print(data)
```

when I run this, nothing happens.  I don't get any errors though.

What could I be doing wrong?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code works for me. It prints:

```
[['Billing', ''], ['Accounting', ''], ['Pediatrics', ''], ['Human Resources', ''], ['Divisional And Surgery', '']]
```

If you see no console output, maybe you should go back to basics and verify that you see the expected output from `print('hello world')`. Then also verify that your `MentorAffiliations.txt` file is saved (maybe it's empty on disk?)

Answer (score 1):

```
with open('file.txt', 'r') as f:
    x = f.read().split(',')
```

This should get you started. Now just add it to your list. If that does not do it for you, then you can use Numpy as follows:

```
from numpy import loadtxt
file = "file.txt"
lines = loadtxt(file, delimiter=',',unpack=False)
```

Then you got your lines ready.